# Run windows bat remotely file from Linux over ssh

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh

It is possible?

Cygwin is installed on the windows environment. I connect to windows environment over ssh with follow command:

ssh user@ip /cygdriver/c/run.bat. After introducing the password the message 'No such file or directory' appears. Any suggestion how I can make it?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're entering 'cygdrive' and not 'cygdriver'
If it doesn't work try to run this command `CMD /C C:\run.bat`

Comment: I tried to execute the follow command ssh Administrator@IP /C C:\run.bat and don't have success.

Comment: it's CMD /C C:\run.bat

Answer (score 0):

Is "cygdriver" the right path?

I suggest trying to make the command work locally in the Cygwin shell on the Windows machine, then copy-and-paste the known-working command into your ssh script which will run remotely.

Comment: sorry, the right path is /cygdrive/c/run.bat

Comment: I can execute the command locally on cygwin using the follow command /cygdrive/c/run.bat